Is there any evidence for/against the idea that single men & single women contribute equally to lower fertility?
This article suggests that one of the reasons for Singapore's low fertility rate (which is less than 1, according to the article) is "the growing share of women remaining single". The article was immediately criticized for appearing to blame single women.

Why are we blaming single women for Singapore's fertility rate? First, it takes two to tango: Where are the stats on single men?

This appears to argue that single men are equally responsible for the low fertility rate. I'm aware that statistics suggest that female education level has a much greater impact on fertility than male education level, so this argument might not be robust even if it is a priori reasonable. Hence the question: is there any evidence for/against the idea that single men contribute equally to lower fertility?
I've tagged this question with singapore, although I am also interested in answers worldwide. If there is no evidence, I am also interested in why the Singaporean Department of Statistics apparently didn't take into account the obvious (?) objection above.

I think this is more of sociology question than politics, frankly. Not everything that is interesting to politicians is politics.

Even if it were on-topic, there would be a lot of definitional issues surrounding the word "responsible" that I think would prevent this from being answered objectively in its current form. For instance, is the more "responsible" sex (a) whichever one has more children per person on average (because someone of that sex would reduce population growth the most by having no children relative to the number that they "should")? Or is it instead (b) the group that has the least children in aggregate (taking the rate of non-reproduction into account)? Or maybe (c) the group most likely to be single?

It would be very hard to make any proper analysis for this as in almost all populations the gender ratio of the entire population is roughly equal, hence the proportion of single women and men are also roughly equal. An exception I once read is a story about fertility in Germany shortly after the end of World War 2. The gender ratio was massively skewed but women got about the same number of babies one would expect if there was an equal number of men around. Not sure whether that is an urban myth though.

Why "blame" anybody at all? Having kids is voluntary activity.

Your Question is not clear to me - obviously if men and women choose to be single, and not mate with long-term commitment in mind, they won't be having kids. If more and more people choose to be single, and not have kids, the birth rate of a country is bound to fall. Right? So why do you think that men choosing to be single won't contribute to lower birth rate?

How would you count things in a society with a large number of single mothers raising kids after the - now single - dad left?  I don't think "single" means much here, but remember that Singapore is socially conservative.  Also, at the end of the day, women can end up having to do a lot more work, so they have more skin in the game and they mostly ought to/seem to weigh more in that decision, meaning that the "outrage" seems misplaced.

The truth is more complicated. It could also be married couples that do not get children or get less children. It could be that people marry later (automatically increasing the single population) and get children later. It could be that both, men and women contribute about equally to the observed birthrate. And finally, if you want to find out and you naively ask something like would you like to have more children, it might be that people do not answer truthfully and it might be that one gender answers more truthfully than the other, which would mislead the naive interpretation.

While this question may be interesting, how is this on-topic for this site?

@sfxedit depends on how you define "single", I suppose. Take three people Alice, Bob and Charlie. Alice marries Bob, has a child, divorces, and marries Charlie. Is Bob now single? If yes, he's a single man with a child.

@Obie2.0 I would wonder how the Singaporean Department of Statistics defined it, but I have not looked at it.

@alamar Curiously the news article doesn't use the word 'blame', although the Instagram post did.

@Allure One of the political context of falling birth-rates is single people unwilling to have children.

Frame challenge: Women are the easier sex to track statistically with respect to that question, so a lot of statistics is going to revolve around the influence of women. However that does not necessarily mean that women actually are the most or only important factor here.
The thing is there are A LOT of factors that can contribute to the fertility rate of a country. Questions of sex ed, access to contraceptives, sex distributions within society, wars and famines, diseases, individual fertility, STIs, psychological issues, some want but can't, some can but don't want, cultural issues, societal factors that make having children more or less beneficial, child mortality rates, social safety nets, retirement, work hours and so on.
However among the things you can actually track statistically the figures that can be traced best are often "how many women exist" and "how many children are born" (and the respective ratios of that). These are the figures you can access the most objectively. In that you might literally have these figures from hospital and citizens records and don't need to eye ball them with statistics.
So a woman going through months of visible pregnancy, medical records and applying or formalities is just massively easier to track than idk the legendary sailor who has a girl in every port, who might have fathered lots of offspring, but never ends up in any statistic.
So it's no coincidence that a lot of that statistics focus on women, just because it's easier to gather those statistics for them. The problem is that it could also be the case that plasticizers or other chemicals make men less fertile and you'd still largely have statistics on women and total fertility and as such would look for correlations in that direction.
So the absence of evidence is not an evidence of absence, it might just be a problem with gathering reliable data.

Housing costs matter as well, though they note that causality, vs correlation, is unclear.
